# WPF/MVVMDo I need a dependency Injection tool like Unity/LightCore when using a ViewModelLocator

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection

I would like to use a ViewModelLocator and I would like to know wether it is a basic requirement using a DI framework to make a ViewModelLocator possible?

Answer (score 0):

The ViewLocator in [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/)/Caliburn uses DI (Reflection but can be swoped out for MEF)

[MEF/MVVM](http://mefmvvm.codeplex.com/) uses MEF for its ViewModelLocator

MVVMLight do not use DI (The code template generates the needed code)

If you want your view/viewModel location logic to be decoupled then you have to use some form of DI.

you also have to decide view first or vm first? Some frameworks work view model first (like caliburn) and others like MVVMLight is view first...

BTW. [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) is one of my favorite frameworks to use...